# Change all select option using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to change the selection options of the 2nd two dropdown menus based on the first selection option change event.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('.TwoSided').click(function() {
  
    var holdthis = jQuery(this);
    $(this).each(function() {
      $(this).find('option:eq(1)').not(this).prop('selected', true);
    });
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="twosided4x10" name="twosided4x10" value="NO" class="thwepo-input-field thwepo-price-field TwoSided thwepo-price-option-field" data-placeholder="">
  <option value="No" data-price-type="normal" data-price="0" name="twosided4x10">No</option>
  <option value="Yes" data-price-type="normal" data-price="56" name="twosided4x10">Yes</option>
</select>


<select id="twosided4x10" name="twosided4x10" value="NO" class="thwepo-input-field thwepo-price-field TwoSided thwepo-price-option-field" data-placeholder="">
  <option value="No" data-price-type="normal" data-price="0" name="twosided4x10">No</option>
  <option value="Yes" data-price-type="normal" data-price="56" name="twosided4x10">Yes</option>
</select>

<select id="twosided4x10" name="twosided4x10" value="NO" class="thwepo-input-field thwepo-price-field TwoSided thwepo-price-option-field" data-placeholder="">
  <option value="No" data-price-type="normal" data-price="0" name="twosided4x10">No</option>
  <option value="Yes" data-price-type="normal" data-price="56" name="twosided4x10">Yes</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Within the event handler, to select all the *other* `select` controls, you can use:

```
$(".TwoSided").not(this)
```

then, using your original `.find` code give using `:eq(1)` you need to loop through those selects, giving:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.TwoSided').change(function() {

    $(".TwoSided").not(this).each(function() {
      $(this).find('option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true);
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="twosided4x10" name="twosided4x10" value="NO" class="thwepo-input-field thwepo-price-field TwoSided thwepo-price-option-field" data-placeholder="">
  <option value="No" data-price-type="normal" data-price="0" name="twosided4x10">No</option>
  <option value="Yes" data-price-type="normal" data-price="56" name="twosided4x10">Yes</option>
</select>


<select id="twosided4x10" name="twosided4x10" value="NO" class="thwepo-input-field thwepo-price-field TwoSided thwepo-price-option-field" data-placeholder="">
  <option value="No" data-price-type="normal" data-price="0" name="twosided4x10">No</option>
  <option value="Yes" data-price-type="normal" data-price="56" name="twosided4x10">Yes</option>
</select>

<select id="twosided4x10" name="twosided4x10" value="NO" class="thwepo-input-field thwepo-price-field TwoSided thwepo-price-option-field" data-placeholder="">
  <option value="No" data-price-type="normal" data-price="0" name="twosided4x10">No</option>
  <option value="Yes" data-price-type="normal" data-price="56" name="twosided4x10">Yes</option>
</select>
```

---

Alternatively, to make it a single line you can use

```
:first-child
```

as

```
$(".TwoSided").not(this).find('option:first-child').prop('selected', true);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.TwoSided').change(function() {

    $(".TwoSided").not(this).find('option:first-child').prop('selected', true);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="twosided4x10" name="twosided4x10" value="NO" class="thwepo-input-field thwepo-price-field TwoSided thwepo-price-option-field" data-placeholder="">
  <option value="No" data-price-type="normal" data-price="0" name="twosided4x10">No</option>
  <option value="Yes" data-price-type="normal" data-price="56" name="twosided4x10">Yes</option>
</select>


<select id="twosided4x10" name="twosided4x10" value="NO" class="thwepo-input-field thwepo-price-field TwoSided thwepo-price-option-field" data-placeholder="">
  <option value="No" data-price-type="normal" data-price="0" name="twosided4x10">No</option>
  <option value="Yes" data-price-type="normal" data-price="56" name="twosided4x10">Yes</option>
</select>

<select id="twosided4x10" name="twosided4x10" value="NO" class="thwepo-input-field thwepo-price-field TwoSided thwepo-price-option-field" data-placeholder="">
  <option value="No" data-price-type="normal" data-price="0" name="twosided4x10">No</option>
  <option value="Yes" data-price-type="normal" data-price="56" name="twosided4x10">Yes</option>
</select>
```